# UNO Card Game- What is the +4 card and how to use it in a game?

Tags: uno

What does the +4 card in UNO mean? Are there any special rules for it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the Wild Draw Four card. The exact rules for it might vary slightly between versions, but here is what I found [online](https://www.unorules.com/)

> Wild – This card represents all four colors, and can be placed on any
> card. The player has to state which color it will represent for the
> next player. It can be played regardless of whether another card is
> available.
>
> Wild Draw Four – This acts just like the wild card except that the
> next player also has to draw four cards as well as forfeit his/her
> turn. With this card, you must have no other alternative cards to play
> that matches the color of the card previously played. If you play this
> card illegally, you may be challenged by the other player to show your
> hand to him/her. If guilty, you need to draw 4 cards. If not, the
> challenger needs to draw 6 cards instead.